# Como recuperar linhas apagado do MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, delete

Eu sem querer apaguei algumas linhas do mysql, por causa de um `LIKE` escrito errado.

Tem como eu recuperar essas linhas?

Não sei se ajuda na reposta, mas o comando para apagar foi:

```
DELETE FROM vids WHERE alias LIKE 'la-%'
```

Comment: Sim, é só baixar o back-up de antes da alteração errada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesse link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112378/how-to-recover-deleted-records-by-mistake-in-mysql) e [nesse outro link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924823/how-to-recover-just-deleted-rows-in-mysql), podem te ajudar

Comment: e se não tiver backup?....rs

Comment: Se não tiver aparece a tarja preta com o famoso texto em vermelho do GTA 5.....**Se F#d3u** kkkkkk

Comment: Se você já deu um commit e não tiver um backup, já era, agora se você não deu commit ou pelo menos não fechou a sessão você consegue desfazer a ação escrevendo rollback